# Haskell command line help from ghci

Tags: haskell, helper

Does `ghci` have built-in help? Put differently, is it possible to get help from within `ghci`?

For example, I want to now all functions that can be applied to a list.

There is a useful command `:info`, which outputs some help, however it is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Not built in, but try [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can type `:?` to get a list of all ghci commands. A very useful tool is **hoogle** which is a seearch engine for the Haskell API. You can search functions by their names or by their types, i.e:

```
(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
foldl
...
```

It provides a short description of the function and a link to its documentation. Hope it helped!

http://www.haskell.org/hoogle

Answer (score 3):

Since `hoogle` was already mentioned. You can easily integrate it into `ghci` by first installing the corresponding hackage package using `cabal`

```
cabal install hoogle
```

and then modifying your `~/.ghci` as follows

```
echo >> ~/.ghci ':def hoogle \x -> return $ ":!hoogle \"" ++ x ++ "\""'
```

After that you can use `:hoogle` from within `ghci`.

**Note:** It might be necessary to do

```
hoogle data
```

on the command line, before the `:hoogle` command in `ghci` works.